# SICK laser scanner not starting with ROS

Tags: python, linux, command-line, ros

I have been trying to to run the SICK LD-MRS scanner with ROS. On the web site [HERE](http://wiki.ros.org/sick_ldmrs) they are saying that you just have to type rosrun sick_ldmrs sickldmrs.py and things should be working. I have downloaded the latest version of the package from the web site, unzipped it and tried to run it. Unfortunately I cannot run the code...The error is that the package sick_ldmrs is not found.Does anyone have any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: did you make (`catkin_make` or `rosmake`) the package first ? looks like a missing step. further info about the make process can be found [here](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/BuildingPackages).

Answer (score 0):

you need input "source devel/setup.bash" after perform "catkin_make"